# non www .htaccess redirect - ignore other subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a .htaccess redirect for "non www" like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it is working. But, i have also some subdomains other than www.
If I call for example http://shop.example.com it redirects me to:
http://www.shop.example.com

I dont want to write the subdomains into the .htaccess file, it should work automatically, just ignore anything else than www and '' like this:

```
if subdomain =='' -> redirect to www.HTTP_HOST....
elseif subdomain !='' && subdomain !='www' -> do nothing.
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}//s%{HTTPS} ^www\.(.*)//((s)on|s.*)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^ http%3://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Just tried it with [internetagentur.drupal-webmaster.de](http://internetagentur.drupal-webmaster.de) (the subdomain) - the main is without www.

Comment: yo Pero! I didnt test it, because I found another solution, through php. I accept your Answer anyway ;) danke.

Answer (score 10):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And to also take HTTPS into account:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you - for reference this solution works for me
server doesn't have an SSL so that part is not tested

Answer (score 0):

If you want a php solution you could use something similar to this:

```
define('URL', 'yourdomain.com/');

// fix : impose www rule
if (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'www') === false ) {
    header('Location: http://www.'.URL.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    die();
}
```

This would also redirect to the originally requested page.