# redirecting only non-www to www - ignoring all subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am surprised that Googling this did not return any useful solution to my problem.

I want to redirect only non-www requests to www.. but if it's a subdomain, I want it to ignore it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects non-www to www, but if I enter a subdomain it appends a "www." in front of it.. I need to stop this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[this answer should do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2720415/1443717)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And to also take HTTPS into account:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i tried your code and it seems to still be redirecting a subdomain to "www.subdomain.example.com"

Comment: that created a loop and kept appending www. infinite times

Comment: added link that should solve your problem (untested) its late xD

Comment: i think my second option would work if you hardcoded the domain (See answer)

Comment: the one that worked was the answer below the accepted answer.. you should post it here

Comment: Working perfectly for http > https, non www > www and not mess with another subdomain!!

Answer (score 1):

I already had to do the same thing and this worked for me

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```